# Does the Affordable Care Act (Obamacare) require insurance to be paid with pre- or post-tax dollars?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, health-insurance

I would like to continue paying for health insurance with pre-tax dollars.  But, according to [this Washington Post article](http://articles.washingtonpost.com/2013-01-07/national/36207987_1_health-insurance-benchmark-plan-karen-pollitz), buying healthcare through the Affordable Care Act (Obamacare) requires **post-tax** dollars.

Is the article accurate, or can I continue to use pre-tax dollars to pay for health insurance?

Comment: Even before Obamacare, you could only deduct medical expenses (including health insurance premiums purchased on the individual market) to the extent they exceeded 7.5% (10% in 2013–) of your income, unless you were self-employed and could deduct it as a business expense.

Comment: Health insurance premiums for self-employed people are not a business expense deductible on Schedule C (where they would reduce taxable income) but are deducted on Form 1040 (Line 29) instead of Schedule A where they would be subject to the 10% threshold. (Premiums for other employees of the business are deductible on Schedule C as a business expense).  Medicare premiums are _also_ deductible on Line 29 even though they are not directly related to the business. At least, this was the law for 2012; I haven't checked whether the Medicare provision has been removed for 2013 and later years.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Am I misunderstanding [this link](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p535/ch06.html#en_US_2012_publink1000208843)?

Comment: @CraigW It is possible that I am mis-understanding the document in the link you provide. But note that the section titled **Self-Employed Health Insurance Deduction** says right up front that premiums for you, spouse, and dependents can be deducted (I didn't include the latter in my comment) and the _last_ sentence of this section says **"Take the deduction on Form 1040, line 29."**  which seems pretty clear to me. The document also says that Medicare premiums for yourself can be deducted. If you have been taking the deduction on Schedule C, I suggest that you consider filing amended returns.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think I misunderstood you. You are saying health insurance premiums are deductible if you are self-employed, just not as a business expense, correct? If so I stand corrected. However, I am pretty sure it is not subject to the 10% threshold. And just for the record, I am not self-employed...

Comment: @CraigW I never said that the health insurance premiums paid by self-employed person (and family) were subject to any 10% threshold because the deduction for this is on Form 1040 and not on Schedule A: the 10% threshold is on Schedule A.

Comment: The tax situation is regarding health care, unrelated to ACA, so you might reword the question if you wish.

Comment: @DilipSarwate sorry, misunderstood you again. We are in agreement now.

Comment: Kevin, claiming that your employer dropped your coverage because of this law is a political statement, since factually it is not true. Also, from your question it might appear that the Washington Post article suggested that *only* premiums for insurance bought through the ACA exchanges is post-tax, which is again incorrect and sourced in a political bias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out, post-tax dollars are what you'll use.  Just as a quick note, as you'll be using `post-tax` dollars; in the past, I've refused to take contractor plans because they almost always are inferior to what I've been able to get off the private exchange ehealthinsurance.  A few people have written excellent articles on Get Rich Slowly [here](http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2010/09/26/reader-story-how-i-purchased-private-health-insurance/) and [here](http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2013/09/04/recalibrating-for-self-employment-health-insurance/) about them in detail if you want more information.

Generally, contractors (and sometimes employees) are offered a few plans (3-4), and this health exchange gives you a little more freedom to pick your plan, which in your situation may help.  It isn't *always* cheaper, but depending on your needs, you may obtain a better deal.

Forgot to add this: this option has also made switching jobs easy as well since I don't have to pay **COBRA**.  While it depends on the situation, this can sometimes come out significantly cheaper.  For instance, if I were to take the employer health plan next year, I would lose ~$450 a month, whereas the private exchange option is ~$300.  But, if I were to switch jobs, decide to opt for self-employment, or a layoff, the **COBRA** would be even higher than ~$450.